# Разработка AR приложения на unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я совсем новичок в программировании и около двух лет пишу на python. Недавно мне была поставлена задача разработки AR приложения для очков от Microsoft Hololens 2. Подскажите что почитать, посмотреть чтобы как можно скорее освоиться в разработке на unity и как лучше учить сам c#, чтобы хватило знаний для данной задачи.

Я просмотрел в сумме около 2 курсов на ютубе по unity, но там все слишком сухо и поверхностно.

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.